# Cannot add 1 to LastIndexOf() method

Tags: c#, argumentexception

I have a method that gets a substring based on the last occurrence of the forward slash character.

```
path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('/'), path.Length - path.LastIndexOf('/') )
```

Given a string `The/quick/brown/fox`, I get a substring result of `/fox`. I would like to get rid of the forward slash character such that I only get `fox` as a result.

I try to add 1 to the `LastIndexOf()` method but I'm getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

```
path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1, path.Length - path.LastIndexOf('/'))
```

The `LastIndexOf()` method returns an `int`, why does adding 1 cause an error?

Comment: `path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1, path.Length - path.LastIndexOf('/') - 1)` Decrement the length you want to get by 1

Comment: I'm not seeing a backslash `\\` anywhere in your post.

Comment: @Glorfindel I meant forward slash. edited the question

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered a simpler `String.Split`?

```
var str = "The/quick/brown/fox";
var result = str.Split('/').Last();

//result = "fox"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your path has `/`, try just [`Substring(int startIndex)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

(In order to make your sample work, you need to deduct `1` from the second parameter which is the length of the required substring.)

But it could be better to use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Path.GetFileName("The/quick/brown/fox");
```

Comment: I think this is a custom Substring method is what it sounds like.

Comment: @Adam Hm, it looks as a regular `string.Substring` to me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is really a path, have a look at the path manipulation functions available in ['System.IO.Path'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx). You will get the desired result with

```
Path.GetFileName(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do better with LINQ:

```
path.Split('/').LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hey Jonesopolis!
I had to answer the phone! :-)